# Error importing Maximum Credibility Tree from BEAST into R using treeio's read.beast()

Tags: r, phylogenetics, phylogeny, bioconductor, ggtree

I've encountered an issue that I'm hoping someone can help with. I constructed a phylogenetic tree using **BEAST1** and then extracted the Maximum Credibility Tree using treeannotator. I'm trying to import it into **R** for editing, but I run into an error when using the `read.beast()` function from the **treeio** package:

```
MCC_tree <- read.beast("/home/MyPC/Downloads/MCC_beast.tre")
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  numbers of left and right parentheses in Newick string not equal
```

Interestingly, when I attempt to visualize the tree using figtree, it works fine. Likewise, importing into R using `read.nexus()` works without issues. However, I want to use `read.beast()` specifically because I need to annotate the "posterior", which I can't do when I import it using `read.nexus()`.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. if you read it into FigTree then in the export in Nexus and perform a "save all trees"  it should then read into `read.beast()`.
2. Use the beast file output before you performed tree annotator operation.

1 or 2. should be read directly into `read.beast()`.
I would try option 2 first.